# How to get proper image in pdf doc with its height and width using zend_pdf class

Tags: zend-framework

I am facing a problem with `zend_pdf` as I am not getting the quality of the image and actual height and width of the image in `zend pdf` documents.

below is the function which I am using

```
 $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();

   $page = $pdf->newPage('510:745:');

   $pdf->pages[] = $page;

   $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($imagePath);

   $page->drawImage($image, 100,100,400, 300);
```

So how can I get the quality of an image with its proper height and width with `Zend_pdf`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the size as original. It would be help to maintain the  original quality of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe getPixelWidth() and getPixelHeight() works better. Like this:

```
$img = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath('myimage.png');
$page->drawImage($img, 0, 0, $img->getPixelWidth(), $img->getPixelHeight());
```